# Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX is not defined, while developing a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome plugin and get XXX is not defined...newbie error...

my manifest

```
"background": { "scripts": ["js/bg.js"] },
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "https://XXXXXX.com/*"
    ],
    "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/contentParser.js"]
```

then my contentParser (just a portion):

```
function ContentParser(app){

    this.loaded = 0;
    this.setting = null;
    this.clicking = false;
    this.selectedLanguages = false;
    this.click = function(object){
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent ("MouseEvent");
        clickEvent.initMouseEvent (
            "click", true, true, window, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 
            false, false, false, false, 
            0, null
        );
        object.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    };
    var self = this;

    $.get(chrome.runtime.getURL('setting.json'), null, function(data){
        self.setting = data;
    }, 'json');
}
```

my bg.js

```
    function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf('https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx') > -1)  {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        }
    }

    chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/translate.js"});
    });

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
        checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab);

        if(changeInfo.status === 'complete'){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/init.js"});
        }
    });
```

then the error comes on my init.js, ContentParser is underlined:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ContentParser is not defined

```
if(typeof document.behouse != 'object'){
    alert ('creem objecte');

    document.contentParser = new ContentParser(this);  // ERROR HERE
    document.contentParser.loaded++;

}
```

as you can see ContentParser.js is already in content_scripts, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The onUpdated listener runs on all tabs, even those where your `content_scripts` doesn't run anything. It's unclear why you use onUpdated instead of simply adding "init.js" in `content_scripts`.

Comment: It appears your extension doesn't know what a `ContentParser` is. Have you imported/ required it into the file?

Comment: @nopassport1 it seems not... how to do it correctly? via content_scripts?

Comment: @wOxxOm OK. I'll try that

Comment: I have checked and as stated above contentParser.js was already in the content_scripts. Adding also init.js has no effect. Same error.

Comment: the onUpdated listener is needed to activate the action button: chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);